# What are the BUGS and RST buttons on the A320's ISIS for?

Tags: airbus-a320

What is the ***BUGS*** and the ***RST*** function for the A320's ISIS for?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The **RST** button is the attitude reset (note the **ATT** next to the button) function. The ISIS contains an attitude gyro that has to be re-aligned periodically.

[image: ATT RST function]
Credit: Smartcockpit.com

The **BUGS** button enables the BUGS function, which allows the crew to enter speed and altitude bugs on the display. The bugs are a visual identifier to aid the crew in maintaining a speed or altitude.

[image: Speed bug]
[image]
Credit: Smartcockpit.com